# スタックオーバーフローの最古の質問って？

Tags: 討議, ハイパーリンク

スタックオーバーフローをつかって３ヶ月近くになります
たくさんの質問をして、そこそこの回答をしてだんだん使い方がわかるようになってきたんですが
ここにきてあることを疑問に思いました

このスタックオーバーフロー日本語版で現在見れる質問のうち最も古い質問ってなんなんでしょうか？

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1

のように `/questions/[質問の投稿番号]` にアクセスすれば一番最初の質問を閲覧できると思いましたがどうやらアクセスできないようです

ベータ版ということですので最初の質問そのものが削除されている可能性もありますので考えを変えて、現在残っている最古の質問が知りたいです。

ニコニコ動画という動画サービスの動画には投稿順に番号が振られており
`http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm[投稿番号]`　でアクセスできるため
もしかしたらこのサイトも同じようにアクセスできるかもしれないと思いましたがだめでした

Comment: ニコニコ動画の最古の動画は「新・豪血寺一族 -煩悩解放 - レッツゴー！陰陽師」という『PS2の格闘ゲーム『新豪血寺一族 -煩悩解放-』で、一定条件を満たすと見られるPV映像』だそうです

Answer (score 6):

StackExchange ネットワークのサイトはSEDEというツールでDBを閲覧することができます。

で、こんな感じでしょうか。

```
select top 100 id as [Post Link]
from posts
where　PostTypeId = 1
order by id asc
```

実行結果： http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/451291

Comment: な、なんだこのすごい機能は！？

Comment: @猫カフェ データエクスプローラです。当サイトはデフォルトに情報を公開するため、当サイトのデータベースを検索する機能があります。一部の情報（特に個人情報・削除された情報・投票歴）は未公開ですが、何かの質問があれば、そこで調べることができます。

Comment: 信用度１万以上なら、[67](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/67)が一番古いです。プライベートベータ（30人以下のユーザーの時期）の最古質問は[69](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69)です。

Comment: @jmac 回答に書いたSQLによれば[69](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/69/8000)がプライベートベータ中で最も古い質問ではないでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist その通りです。69を書こうとしましたが、７９を入れてしまって、そしてリンクは８２に言っていました。すみませんでした！